# How to rollback in case a Cloud Function failed to execute?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

**My goal is to make sure to create a document if an admin create new user.**

What I've done is writing a Cloud Function and relying on firebase admin SDK.

The current result is sometimes the cloud function failed to execute and only create new user. I suspect this because of nested promises.

This is a workable cloud function, it just does not rollback if one of the promise failed.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
exports.createUser = functions
  .region("asia-southeast2")
  .https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if (!context.auth) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "failed-precondition",
        "The function must be called " + "while authenticated."
      );
    }

    // question: how to combine promises?
    return admin
      .auth()
      .createUser(data)
      .then((user) => {
        return admin
          .firestore()
          .collection("user")
          .doc(user.uid)
          .set({
            access_rights: {
              administration: data.administration,
              purchase: data.purchase,
              inventory: data.inventory,
              sales: data.sales,
            },
            name: data.displayName,
            email: data.email,
            street: data.street,
            city: data.city,
            zip: data.zip,
            phone: data.phone,
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError(error.code, error.message);
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(error.code, error.message);
      });
  });
```

Comment: You will have to write code to undo the specific actions that succeeded if there was a later action that failed.  There is no simple "rollback" command.

Comment: I wrote a simple rollback but it took 4s to finish, is this acceptable in a production environment? @DougStevenson I will write the script in the answer section.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple rollback but it took 4 seconds to finish. Feel free to add improvement, I will certainly marked it as answer.

The idea is simple: a onCall function `createUser` is called by the front-end, the function also receives a payload.

1. If the createUser process failed, it will throws an error.
2. If the createUser process is successful. It will call the `createDocument()`. `createDocument()` can callback itself in case an error occured.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

function createDocument({ user, data }) {
  console.log("createDocument(), user.uid", user.uid, typeof user.uid);
  admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("user")
    .doc(user.uid)
    .set({
      access_rights: {
        administration: data.administration,
        purchase: data.purchase,
        inventory: data.inventory,
        sales: data.sales,
      },
      name: data.displayName,
      email: data.email,
      street: data.street,
      city: data.city,
      zip: data.zip,
      phone: data.phone,
    })
    .then(console.log("createDocument() DONE"))
    .catch(() => {
      console.log("createDocument() catch()");
      return createDocument({ user, data });
    });
}

exports.createUser = functions
  .region("asia-southeast2")
  .https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if (!context.auth) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "failed-precondition",
        "The function must be called " + "while authenticated."
      );
    }

    return admin
      .auth()
      .createUser(data)
      .then((response) => {
        return createDocument({ user: response, data });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(error.code, error.message);
      });
  });
```